# maven Release error through jenkins pipleline

Tags: maven

I was trying to attempt maven release through Jenkins , but running with below error. Can any one faced this kind of error.
    any help on this issue will be appreciate, we running issue in production

```
**error logs**

    ----------
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:rollback (default-cli) on project AuthorizedEventServiceParent: Cannot restore from a missing backup POM: /opt/Jenkins/workspace/uthorizedEventServiceParent-45I6W7JFLSTHNWDJCYNAQKDWWSVTP7CN5RGR35I3VBKTCW5V7WMQ/pom.xml.releaseBackup
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot restore from a missing backup POM: /opt/Jenkins/workspace/uthorizedEventServiceParent-45I6W7JFLSTHNWDJCYNAQKDWWSVTP7CN5RGR35I3VBKTCW5V7WMQ/pom.xml.releaseBackup
            at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.RollbackReleaseMojo.execute(RollbackReleaseMojo.java:59)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Cannot restore from a missing backup POM: /opt/Jenkins/workspace/uthorizedEventServiceParent-45I6W7JFLSTHNWDJCYNAQKDWWSVTP7CN5RGR35I3VBKTCW5V7WMQ/pom.xml.releaseBackup
            at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RestoreBackupPomsPhase.restorePomBackup(RestoreBackupPomsPhase.java:90)
            at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RestoreBackupPomsPhase.execute(RestoreBackupPomsPhase.java:67)
            at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.rollback(DefaultReleaseManager.java:304)
            at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.rollback(DefaultReleaseManager.java:283)
            at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.rollback(DefaultReleaseManager.java:269)
            at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.RollbackReleaseMojo.execute(RollbackReleaseMojo.java:55)
            ... 21 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

----------
```

Regards,
Manojkumar

Comment: Why is `release:rollback` called?

Comment: sorry by mistake I coped wrong stack trace.

Comment: By mistake i copied wrong stack trace :
Correct one logs:

ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project OnePaymentParent: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
[ERROR] [OnePaymentEJB/ejbModule/com/ibm/ejs/container/_EJSWrapper_Stub.java:modified]
[ERROR] [OnePaymentEJB/ejbModule/com/thrivent/onepayment/dto/ResponseDTO.java:modified]
[ERROR]